# MonoDroid drawable.createfromstream

Tags: android, drawable, xamarin.android

I'm reading an image from my sqlite db into a MemoryStream. I seek to the beginning of my memory stream and then pass it to the Drawable.CreateFromStream and it crashes. I've checked the stream contains correct data by saving it to file and opening the file.

can't find any samples on how to load an image that is not in resources into an imageView.

any help?

Comment: post your logcat and code where its crashing it might be that crash is due to some other problem

Answer (score 0):

```
private static InputStream fetch(String urlString)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    conn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return conn.getInputStream();
}

Resources res;
// ***********New Function For Fetching
public static Drawable LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    Drawable drawable = null; Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        if (fetch(URL) != null) {
            try {
                InputStream obj = (InputStream)fetch(URL);
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(obj,null,options);
                obj.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            } catch(OutOfMemoryError e){}
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            return drawable;
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        DefaultDisplay.mContext.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.profileplaceholder);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            return drawable;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("GUIMethodClasas", "fetchDrawable failed", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is a function for fetching a image from a URL. In this function I fetch data from a URL and put it into InputStream by the Fetch function then convert this stream into Drawable and Bitmap object.

In your case you should read an image from the SQLite db and put into the input stream then create image from stream just like I have done in the above function.

Comment: You're using the function Fetch twice, making two calls to request the image. Try fetch once into the obj stream and then check the obj if thats null. Just a thought.